# Laravel concat query return 0 items

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

Here is my controller code:

```php
if ($request->exists('tipo')) {
    $valor = $request->value;
    $candidates = Candidate::buscarpor($tipo, $valor)
                           ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                           ->Paginate(5)
                           ->withQueryString();
    dd($candidates);
}
```

And this is the scope "buscarpor" inside my "Candidate" model:

```php
public function scopeBuscarpor($query, $tipo, $valor)
{
    if(($tipo) && ($valor)) {
        if($tipo == 'names') {
            // return $query->orWhereRaw("concat(name, ' ', last_name) like '%".$valor."%' ");
            return $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT('name', ' ', 'last_name')"), 'like', '%'.$valor.'%')
                         ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('last_name', ' ', 'name')"), 'like', '%'.$valor.'%');
        }
            
        return $query->where($tipo, 'like', "%$valor%");
    }
}
```

When the search is of type "names" I should query in the DB to search a candidate/person by using his first name or last name, I only have one input type text, I just writting all his names is this input type text.

The variable $valor inside of this scope has data and no problem with it.. I tested adding a name that exists in my database but it returns 0 items.

This my `dd($candidates)` output.

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please guys if you have some idea about how fix this problem, I will appreciate it.. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the where expressions are not correctly formed. Try writing it like this

```php
$query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT('name', ' ', 'last_name') like '%?%'", [$valor]))
      ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT('last_name', ' ', 'name') like '%?%'", [$valor]));
```

You can also use the `whereRaw()` syntax instead

```php
$query->whereRaw("CONCAT('name', ' ', 'last_name') like '%?%'", [$valor])
      ->orWhereRaw("CONCAT('last_name', ' ', 'name') like '%?%'", [$valor]);
```

Or maybe the names are written with capital letters in the database? If you are using postgreSQL, you can use `ilike` instead of `like` for a case insensitive search.

If you're using MySQL, you might have to use `lower()` in your raw methods.

```php
$query->whereRaw("LOWER(CONCAT('name', ' ', 'last_name')) like '%?%'", [$valor])
      ->orWhereRaw("LOWER(CONCAT('last_name', ' ', 'name')) like '%?%'", [$valor]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much bro.. But I also I can't get results.. the query does not returns any result.  Here is a pick of my bd https://imgur.com/a/jzni14V I also I'm using softdeletes.. but that query should returns all the results.. I tested ->whereNull('deleted_at'); but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using mysql?

Comment: A possibility is to replace every space in the search string with a wildcard character. (`$valor = str_replace(' ', '%', $valor);`).

Comment: Finally we fix this problem using: `return $query->where(function ($q) use ($valor) {
                    $q->whereRaw("lower(concat(name, ' ', last_name)) like '%$valor%'")
                          ->orWhereRaw("lower(concat(last_name, ' ', name)) like '%$valor%'");
                });` thanks so much bro..